# Uncaught ReferenceError: jwt_decode is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project and am stuck at this part where i am trying to retrieve the profile information on the account im currently logged into using the token. While using the JWT-decoding library i am constantly faced with the issue of jwt_decode is not defined. will need some guidance

I have tried using require but that did not work as well, import will not be usable as i am not using esm. I have also included the cdn to jwt_decode in my html file but its still not working

here is the relevant code in my html and js in 2 different files:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jwt-decode@3.1.2/dist/jwt-decode.min.js"></script>

const authToken = localStorage.getItem("token"); // Retrieve authToken from localStorage
const decodedToken = jwt_decode(authToken); // Change jwtDecode to jwt_decode
const user_id = decodedToken.user_id;

fetchMethod(currentUrl + `/api/users/${user_id}`, callback, "GET");
```

error in my browser console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jwt_decode is not defined
    at profile.js:2:22
```

Comment: Open the file https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jwt-decode@3.1.2/dist/jwt-decode.min.js and look at it

Answer (score 0):

the cdn you are using is wrong

use this one `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jwt-decode@3.1.2/build/jwt-decode.min.js`

Your full code will be

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jwt-decode@3.1.2/build/jwt-decode.min.js"></script>
const authToken = localStorage.getItem("token"); // Retrieve authToken from localStorage
const decodedToken = jwt_decode(authToken); // Change jwtDecode to jwt_decode
const user_id = decodedToken.user_id;

fetchMethod(currentUrl + `/api/users/${user_id}`, callback, "GET");
```

Check the [doc](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/jwt-decode?version=3.1.2)